Fantasy movie involving a wizard who made a tree disappear and reappear, and two friends who were separated then reunited after 15 years
I'm trying to find the name of a movie that I think was on a streaming media service called Plex in autumn 2021 (I cannot remember the exact month).
I watched about 30 minutes of this movie; this is what I remember:
There was a wizard who showed two people that he could make things disappear, including a tree, and he made the tree reappear. The two people were close friends but got separated by some kind of social commotion. They then reunite after 15 years.
I was too tired to continue watching the rest of the movie, so I closed it without saving it to watch later. Any help would be cool, thanks.

Not sure if this is it, but it does sound similar in parts to the 2006 film The Illusionist:

Eisenheim was born Eduard Abramovich, the son of a carpenter, and became interested in magic. He fell in love with Sophie, the Duchess von Teschen, but they were forbidden to see each other as Eduard was a peasant. They kept meeting secretly but were caught and separated by force. Eisenheim studied magic by travelling the world, and 15 years later, returned to Vienna to perform. During one performance, he encounters the adult Sophie and learns that she is expected to marry the Crown Prince Leopold, who, it is rumored, is brutal towards women and even murdered one.

Also, in one scene Eisenheim performs a magic show in which he causes an orange tree to rapidly grow from seed and bear fruit:




Ahhh I recognise the scenes at the beginning, thanks! :)
